NuGet Packages breaking when Adding a migration using dotnet EF
When creating a new migration (in my case I wanted to create my first migration of the project) trying to create a database using SQLite, the build fails and the NuGet packages got error signa over them. The packages with errors are : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. I followed a video and did step by step exactly what the tutorial did and got this build error for some reason. Saw online a lot of people that were talking about the versions of the packages not matching but I think mine are fine. This is my .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite" Version="8.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

This error occurs ONLY if I try to add a new migration, if I install them normally and leave it as is, the code has no errors and neither the packages.
Any reason why this is happening?
I tried uninstalling and installing them again because at first, if I remember correctly, I think the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite package was having errors as well but for some reason after uninstalling and installing them again this exact one seems to be fine while the other two, previously mentioned, got errors on them.

You mention quite a lot that you have errors - what would be most helpful is if you would tell us exactly what those errors are...

^^ and how exactly you went about creating the migration.
